# Postgres functions how to return an array of multiple elements

Tags: postgresql, function

I want to create a function to return an array of multiple elements, the query work perfect but I can't execute as function because I'm getting error always, this is my function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.buscarexamen(visit anyelement)
 RETURNS anyelement
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
return array(SELECT fn_folio_paciente(vi.clave_unilabor, vi.fecha, vi.consec) AS folio_paciente,
    vi.cve_visita, gp.nombre AS nombre_grupo, gp.cve_grupo,    
    --
    vp.cve_visita_prueba, p.cve_prueba, p.nombre AS nombre_prueba, me.nombre AS nombre_metodo,
    --
    gcf.visible AS visible_grupo,
    cf.cve_grupo_campo_formato, gc.nombre_grupo_campo AS grupo_parametro, cf.nombre AS nombre_parametro,
    cf.orden, cf.tipo_dato, cf.solo_lectura AS tipo_titulo,
    cf.cve_seccion_padre, cf.tiene_elementos_seccion, cf.observacion AS observacion_parametro,
    --
    pr.cve_prueba_resultado, pr.tipo_formato_prueba AS tipo_formato, pr.cantidad_resultado AS cantidad_parametro,
    pr.observaciones AS observacion_analista, pr.observaciones_prueba,
    CASE
      WHEN (TRIM(pr.observaciones) <> '') OR  (TRIM(pr.observaciones_prueba) <> '') THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END AS prueba_tiene_observacion,
    --
    rc.cve_resultado_campo, rc.resultado, rc.observacion AS observacion_resultado, rc.signo, rc.decimales, cf.xleft as cursiva,
    vr.valor_referencia_min, vr.valor_referencia_max, un.nombre AS nombre_unidad,
    cf.tiene_valores_referencia
FROM visitas vi
    JOIN corporativo.unilabor_unidades uu ON (vi.cve_unilabor_unidad = uu.cve_unilabor_unidad)
    JOIN visita_pruebas vp ON (vi.cve_visita = vp.cve_visita)
    JOIN prueba_resultados pr ON (vp.cve_visita_prueba = pr.cve_visita_prueba)
    JOIN prueba_metodo pm ON (pr.cve_prueba_metodo = pm.cve_prueba_metodo)
    JOIN metodos me ON (pm.cve_metodo = me.cve_metodo)
    JOIN pruebas p ON (pr.cve_prueba = p.cve_prueba)
    JOIN grupos gh ON (p.cve_grupo = gh.cve_grupo)
    JOIN grupos gp ON (gh.cve_grupo_padre = gp.cve_grupo)
    JOIN pacientes pa ON (vi.cve_paciente = pa.cve_paciente)
    JOIN contratos co ON (vi.cve_contrato = co.cve_contrato AND co.contrato_cerrado = 0)
    JOIN resultados_campos rc ON (pr.cve_prueba_resultado = rc.cve_prueba_resultado)
    JOIN unidades un ON (rc.cve_unidad = un.cve_unidad)
    LEFT JOIN valor_referencia_resultado vr ON (rc.cve_resultado_campo = vr.cve_resultado_campo)
    JOIN campos_formatos cf ON (rc.cve_campo_formato = cf.cve_campo_formato)
    JOIN grupos_campos_formato gcf ON (cf.cve_grupo_campo_formato = gcf.cve_grupo_campo_formato)
    JOIN grupos_campos gc ON (gcf.cve_grupo_campo = gc.cve_grupo_campo)
WHERE vi.cve_visita = 696787
    AND cf.solo_lectura = 0
ORDER BY p.orden_prueba, pr.cve_prueba_resultado, gcf.orden_grupo, rc.orden_local, vr.orden_valor);
    END;
$function$
;
```

I try to use:

```
select * from buscarexamen(123123);
```

On SQL Script return this:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: subquery must return only one column Where: PL/pgSQL function buscarexamen(anyelement) line 3 at RETURN
```

Really I spend a lot of time finding solutions but until now isn't working.

Any help is really apreciated.

Regards.

Comment: And how do you envision an array element of several columns would look like or, to more precise, what would be its type?

Comment: `anyelement` implies a single data item of any data typen but still * a single data item*. An array is not a single data item. It would seem you need `anyarray`.  See [PostgreSQL Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/extend-type-system.html#id-1.8.3.5.12).

Answer (score 0):

Your objective sounds like strange. However you should be able to achieve it by creating a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) `your_composite_type` :

```
CREATE TYPE your_composite_type AS
( folio_paciente folio_paciente_data_type
, cve_visita cve_visita_data_type
, nombre_grupo nombre_grupo_data_type
, cve_grupo cve_grupo_data_type
, cve_visita_prueba cve_visita_prueba_data_type
, cve_prueba cve_prueba_data_type
, nombre_prueba nombre_prueba_data_type
, nombre_metodo nombre_metodo_data_type
, visible_grupo visible_grupo_data_type
, [...]
, nombre_unidad nombre_unidad_data_type
, tiene_valores_referencia tiene_valores_referencia_data_type
) ;
```

Then the function `public.buscarexamen()` can return an array of data type `your_composite_type`  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.buscarexamen(visit anyelement)
 RETURNS your_composite_type[] -- instead of anyarray
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
return array(SELECT row( fn_folio_paciente(...)
                       , vi.cve_visita, gp.nombre, gp.cve_grupo
                       , [...]
                       , vr.valor_referencia_min, vr.valor_referencia_max, un.nombre 
                       , cf.tiene_valores_referencia
                       ) :: your_composite_type
               FROM visitas vi
               JOIN [...]
              WHERE [...]
              ORDER BY p.orden_prueba, pr.cve_prueba_resultado, gcf.orden_grupo, rc.orden_local, vr.orden_valor)
            ) ;
END;
$function$
;
```